# VS Code + Chrome debug + nrwl architecture

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, nrwl, nrwl-nx

Have you been able to debug an application in chrome developed using nx.dev?

https://nx.dev/angular

It looks like when you choose for NX you lose debugging capabilities. The generated .map.js files contains relative paths to source files but are missing the two initial directories where the files are located so the debugger for chrome installed inside vs-code is unable to bind breakpoints.

[image: This is minimal code generated following instructions form link above]

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me, is that you need to set in your angular.json the "root" property of your project to an empty string.

```
 "catalog": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/catalog/catalog/src",
```

But be aware, this can break other functionalities

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, this is what I did and it worked well. Thank you for your accurate response

Comment: glad that I could help, but to be honest, not sure what the drawbacks are for removing the root path... let me know if you find one!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a downside to setting root:"",

1. nx dep-graph gets confused and shows dependencies to the wrong app.
2. nx g move --project  folder/ gets confused and says one or more projects have the same root.

I deduce this is not the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: I have several apps in an nx workspace each lazy loading libs. I got things to work using this...     {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Designer",
      "url": "http://localhost:4204",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/designer",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "webpack:///*": "*",
        "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
        "meteor://app/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    },

Comment: Hi Alain, thank you for the input. I agree about the downsides because they happen to me as well. Hopefully this topic should be in NX developer's radar and they come up with a proper solution. Either, they handle the launch.json file or they fix how nx dev-graph and nx g move works

Comment: @Alaind'Espaignet - the launch.json you described works for me. Thanks for figuring out the sourceMapPathOverrides!

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to the question, it should be a comment on the accepted answer